# Batch File Assistance

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file with a few lines of code as below. I have saved it as `Label.bat`. I need to run it on multiple servers, around 50+ servers. I cannot use any tool like `PSEXEC`. I need a batch file which will run my `Label.bat` on multiple servers. I am not a coder. Please assist me with the code. It would be highly appreciable.

```
@echo off
NET USER Temp1 /COMMENT:" FR/II//TEMP/"
NET USER Temp2 /COMMENT:" FR/II//TEMP/"
exit
```

Comment: Take a look at [WINRS](https://ss64.com/nt/winrs.html). But you can probably do this with Powershell as well.

Comment: And don't call it `label.bat` since `label` is an existing command.